# gstreamer rtsp playback process understanding

Tags: media-player, gstreamer, media, gstreamer-1.0

I tried to make gstreamer pipeline for playback my RTSP(CCTV) and I succeed that.

```
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug-level=3 rtspsrc location="rtsp://192.168.11.200:554/1/stream1" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! openh264dec ! autovideosink
```

I already read the gstreamer document, But I don`t understand my these middle elements (rtph265depay, h264parse, openh264dec) is needed. I think this problem because I am a basic level for processing media data.

could you please any information(site or link) for understanding this flow? I want to use another element like tcpsrc, 265encoding, etc...

Comment: All these elements are different processing blocks for handling the formats involved in your transmission. Your question is rather unspecific.. I suggest reading on video compression and network transmission - specifiications, protocols etc..

Comment: @FlorianZwoch Thanks for your comment. Actually, I don't know what kind of elements` role. Because Many Elements` Description section in the official document is empty...